# How to make all rows invisible that do not contain numbers in a column

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2010

How do I make all rows invisible except for the row with numbers in column G?  Is something like this possible?

[image]

There are number [filters](https://www.extendoffice.com/documents/excel/2975-excel-hide-row-based-on-cell-value.html), though this is not what I am after.

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following:

```
Dim MyRange As Range
Dim iCounter As Long

Set MyRange = ActiveSheet.UsedRange
For iCounter = MyRange.Rows.Count To 1 Step -1
   If Application.CountA(Rows(iCounter).EntireRow) = 0 Then
   Rows(iCounter).EntireRow.Hidden = True
   End If
Next iCounter
```